# Деплой java telegram bot на Heroku. Procfile

Tags: java, heroku

Ссылка на проек Github (https://github.com/Sadfroggy0/TGBOT.git).

Ошибка в том, что не правильно указываю main class (В моем проекте - Bot).
Как правильно указать Procfile для моего проекта?
Логи с heroku:

```
2021-09-04T17:55:33.768762+00:00 app[worker.1]: sh: 0: Can't open target/classes/company/Bot

2021-09-04T17:55:33.806797+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 127

2021-09-04T17:55:33.858648+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

Procfile

```
worker: sh target/classes/company/Bot`
```

Pom.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>TGBOT</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>16</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>16</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
            <artifactId>telegrambots</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <assembleDirectory>target</assembleDirectory>
                <programs>
                    <program>
                        <mainClass>com.company.Bot</mainClass>
                        <name>TGBOT</name>
                    </program>
                </programs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>assemble</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    <plugin>

        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После того, как код для бота был написан, нужно:

1. создать в корне проекта *Procfile*
   2)после этого создаем jar file проекта с помощью команды в консоле "mvn clean package" в корне проекта.
2. вписываем в Procfile строку *worker: sh target/bin/TGBOT*(для проекта созданного с поомщью LongPollingBot, в иных случаях используют *web*)
3. Пишем heroku login в консоле, находясь в корне проекта
4. heroku *ps:scale -a APP_NAME worker=1* пишем в консоли для запуска DYNOS на сервере Heroku.
5. Довольствуемся результатом